# Android how to monitor the app consumtion of memory

Tags: java, android, arrays, memory-management, vector

In my application I show a very long array of a complex object.
The array is saved in the sqlite database (each row of the table is an attribute)
I'd like charge the array dinamically because it contains data for the user and depending on user interaction the app will need between 10 and 250 entries.
How can I monitor the memory I'm talking with different vector size for estimating the best buffer size? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813

Answer (score 2):

[DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) contains an allocation tracker for Android.